# How to use an Lua API declaration file in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, lua

I am trying to get autocomplete working in VSCode for a Lua library called SASL (1-sim.com). The library provides an `api.lua` file, which has declarations for all the functions inside.

How do I get VSCode to *recognize* this and add it to my autocomplete, *without using* ***require****?*
I cannot use *require* because it breaks the project.

If the above is not possible, do I have to write a plugin/extension? Is there another option?